# Adding multiple test scores to student class

Tags: java

Modify the Student class presented in Ch7 of the textbook as follows: 
Each student object should also contain the scores for three different tests. Initialize all test scores initially to zero in the existing constructor. Create a second constructor (or overload the constructor) to set all instance values based on parameter argument values. 
Provide this methods:

`setTestScore`: accepts two parameters, the test number (1 through 3) and the score.

`getTestScore`: accepts the test number and returns the appropriate score.

`average`: computes and returns the average test score for the student.

`toString`: the test scores and average are included in the description of the student.

after that modify the driver class main method to demonstrate the new Student methods.

I am stuck at the part where it (prompts?) accepts the test number (1-3) and then chooses the test score based on the number. However, I don't think I can input any integer if it's straight from the class.

```
package StudentBody;

public class StudentBody {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Address school = new Address("800 Lancaster Ave.", "Villanova", "PA", 19085);
    Address jHome = new Address("21 Jump Street", "Blacksburg", "VA", 24551);

    Student john = new Student("John", "Smith", jHome, school);

    Address mHome = new Address("123 Main Street", "Euclid", "OH", 44132);
    Student marsha = new Student("Marsha", "Jones", mHome, school);

    System.out.println(john);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(marsha);

    }
}

public class Student {

private String firstName, lastName;
private Address homeAddress, schoolAddress;
private double score1, score2, score3;
private int testnumber;

public Student(String first, String last, Address home, Address school)
{
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    homeAddress = home;
    schoolAddress = school;
    score1 = 0;
    score2 = 0;
    score3 = 0;
    testnumber = 0;
}
public Student(double score1_, double score2_, double score3_, int testnumber_)
{
    score1 = score1_;
    score2 = score2_;
    score3 = score3_;
    testnumber = testnumber_;
}
public void setTestScore(double score1_1, double score2_1, double score3_1, int testnumber1_1)
{
    score1 = score1_1;
    score2 = score2_1;
    score3 = score3_1;
    testnumber = testnumber1_1;
}
public double getTestScore()
{

}
public String toString()
{
    String result;

    result = firstName + " " + lastName + "\n";
    result += "Home Address:\n" + homeAddress + "\n";
    result += "School Address:" + schoolAddress;

    return result;
    }
}


public class Address {  
private String streetAddress, city, state;
private long zipCode;

public Address(String street, String town, String st, long zip)
{
    streetAddress = street;
    city = town;
    state = st;
    zipCode = zip;
}
public String toString()
{
    String result;

    result = streetAddress + "\n";
    result += city + ", " + state + " " + zipCode;

    return result;
}

}
```

Comment: Input as a comma seperated value e.g. `10,12,5` and then use String::split to get each individual value

Comment: I think use a array like score = new int[3] to save scores and get only one number as mentioned by you in your description of method and return related part of array or set related part. (because method must get only two parameter, test number and score) I thnik you do something wrong because you accept three number

Comment: Note: you shouldn't use underscores within identifiers in Java. The Java Naming Conventions discourage it. Also, package names should not contain uppercase characters.

Comment: Simplest way is you can use HashMap<Integer,Double> with has put and get method put has two argument 1st is Integer which you can call test number and second is Double that is score. And to get the score you can use get which take  parameter as integer that is your test number. To find average you can use Map.entrySet().iterator() and find average.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have used scores and test number as variables i.e. as below

```
private double score1, score2, score3;
private int testnumber;
```

Instead, try this is as a `hashMap` .Change your code from

```
    public void setTestScore(double score1_1, double score2_1, double score3_1, int testnumber1_1)
{
    score1 = score1_1;
    score2 = score2_1;
    score3 = score3_1;
    testnumber = testnumber1_1;
}
```

to the below code:

```
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> score;
    public void setTestScore( int testnumber,double score)
{
    score.put(testnumber,score);
}
```

Also, in the initial Constructor, set the hashMap values to zero.

```
    testMarks.put(1, 0);
    testMarks.put(2, 0);
    testMarks.put(3, 0);//1,2,3 are the test numbers
```

Also, you dont need 2 constructors here, as the overloaded constructor and the setTestScore looks the same. So, go with the initial constructor and remove the overloaded constructor from your code.

Answer (score -1):

I think your implementation is not correct correspond to your description at the first of your question. I modified your code to understand how to do that:
(**Updated to do not use array**)

```
public class StudentBody
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Address school = new Address("800 Lancaster Ave.", "Villanova", "PA", 19085);
        Address jHome = new Address("21 Jump Street", "Blacksburg", "VA", 24551);
        Address mHome = new Address("123 Main Street", "Euclid", "OH", 44132);

        Student john = new Student("John", "Smith", jHome, school);
        Student marsha = new Student("Marsha", "Jones", mHome, school);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testNumber = in.nextInt(); // ask for test number

        System.out.println(john.getTestScore(testNumber));
        System.out.println(marsha.getTestScore(testNumber));

        // rest of your code
    }
}

class Student
{
    private String firstName, lastName;
    private Address homeAddress, schoolAddress;
    private double score1, score2, score3;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, Address homeAddress, Address schoolAddress) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
        this.schoolAddress = schoolAddress;
        // there is no need for score1 = score2 = score3 = 0; it is their default value
        // when object created.
    }

    public void setTestScore(int testNumber, double newScore) {
        if (testNumber < 1 || testNumber > 3) {
            // do something because test number is wrong
        }
        if (testNumber == 1)
            score1 = newScore;
        else if (testNumber == 2)
            score2 = newScore;
        else
            score3 = newScore;
    }

    public double getTestScore(int testNumber) {
        if (testNumber < 1 || testNumber > 3) {
            // do something because test number is wrong
        }
        if (testNumber == 1)
            return score1;
        else if (testNumber == 2)
            return score2;
        else
            return score3;
    }

    public double average() {
        return (score1 + score2 + score3) / 3;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Scores: " + score1 + " , " + score2 + " , " + score3 +
                " " + " average: " + average();
    }
}

class Address
{
    // same as you
}
```

I'm sorry for too much code. I hope this is what you want.

Comment: I'm not using arrays yet, this project can be done without arrays

Comment: @Markusovic ok. I'm edit it so it doesn't use arrays anymore. I hope this solve problem.